# Why can method parameters be locked in scala

Tags: scala

I'm confused. In Scala, like code:

```
def remove(timerTaskEntry: TimerTaskEntry): Unit = {
  synchronized {
    timerTaskEntry.synchronized {
      if (timerTaskEntry.list eq this) {
        timerTaskEntry.next.prev = timerTaskEntry.prev
        timerTaskEntry.prev.next = timerTaskEntry.next
        timerTaskEntry.next = null
        timerTaskEntry.prev = null
        timerTaskEntry.list = null
        taskCounter.decrementAndGet()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What do these two `synchronized` mean? Why parameter can also be locked?
How can realize parameter lock in Java?

Comment: Note that it is weird to use this basic **Java** synchronization in **Scala**. So it is probably that the code base you are looking is not really idiomatic and not taking advantage of the features of the language.

Answer (score 4):

This is Java (or JVM in general) [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

`something.synchronized { code }` in Scala means the same thing as `synchronized(something) { code }` in Java.

Additionally, `synchronized { code }` is a shorthand for `this.synchronized { code }`, i.e. `synchronized(this) { code }` in Java.